# Como apagar dados do google Maps

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Eu tenho uma app em ionic que faz uso do google maps. Nesse mapa exibo informações que o usuário fornece. Por exemplo: O usuário quer fazer uma denúncia que irá aparecer no mapa. Porém, se o usuário, em outro momento, quiser fazer outra denúncia, as novas informações deve aparecer. Então, preciso apagar as informações antigas para exibir as novas. Como posso fazer isso?

Meu código em angular:

```
.controller('MapaResCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

$rootScope.diaDenun;
$rootScope.hora;
$rootScope.tipo;
$rootScope.des;
$rootScope.coordenadas;


var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
    $rootScope.myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: "My Location",
        //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Dia da denúncia "+$rootScope.diaDenun+" Hora: "+$rootScope.hora+" Tipo: "+$rootScope.tipo+" Descrição: "+$rootScope.des
      });

    infowindow.open(map,$rootScope.myLocation);
});

$scope.map = map;

})
```

Print de como as informações aparecem no mapa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua implementação de interface com o Google Maps não necessita de alteração alguma.

Os valores estão sendo lidos a partir de variáveis criadas em `$rootScope`:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 
            "Dia da denúncia "+ $rootScope.diaDenun + 
            " Hora: " + $rootScope.hora +
            " Tipo: " + $rootScope.tipo + 
            " Descrição: "+$rootScope.des
      });
```

Caso você deseje exibir outros valores, verifique a parte de seu código que popula as propriedades `diaDenun`, `hora`, `tipo` e `des` de `$rootScope`.

Comment: Beleza, mas o que devo verificar nesses dados? Tenho que apagar os dados deles, após a exibição?

Comment: De acordo com sua pergunta - *se o usuário, em outro momento, quiser fazer outra denúncia, as novas informações devem aparecer* - eu diria que sua fonte de dados deve popular essas propriedades (diaDenun, hora, tipo e des) com os novos valores. Isso dependerá de como a aplicação está implementada.

Comment: Devo setar essas variáveis como null, após o mapa ser exibido com essa informações?

Comment: Essas informações vem de uma formulário, que o usuário preenche.

Comment: Você pode monitorar as alterações do usuário, e alterar a propriedade `content` de `infowindow` para exibir os novos valores.

Comment: Putzzz, mas e como faço isso?

Comment: Eu sugeriria criar uma nova pergunta contendo o código tanto do formulário utilizado pelo usuário da view contendo este mapa, já que a resposta fugiria um pouco ao escopo desta pergunta.

Comment: Cara, eu acho que vc sabe como fazer o que vc sugeriu, não precisaria abrir outro tópico pra explicar isso.
Ou te passo meu email para isso: gustavo.msevero@gmail.com.
Agradeço, desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Todo marcador têm um mapa setado à ele. Para remover o marcador do mapa, você precisa setar o mapa como `null`. Dessa forma:

`$rootScope.myLocation.setMap(null);`

Veja um exemplo detalhado em: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: Mas não é isso que quero, não com relação a marca, mas sim, com relação às informações que aparecem.